# How to determine transformation matrix having coordinate pairs?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, linear-algebra

So. I have 4 sets of coordinate pairs. One in world coordinates and other in camera coordinates.

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Xw  | Yw  | Zw  | Xc  | Yc  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 0,0 | 0,0 | 0,0 | 582 | 344 |
| 7,0 | 0,0 | 0,0 | 834 | 338 |
| 0,0 | 5,0 | 0,0 | 586 | 529 |
| 7,0 | 5,0 | 0,0 | 841 | 522 |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

> `Xw, Yw, Zw` - World coordinates 
>  `Xc, Yc` - Camera coordinates
>   
>  `Zw` - is always 0

Now i need to calculate a transform matrix for that. So having Xw and Yw i can produce Xc, Yc.

Also i have camera 2. And then, using some point position from camera 2, i need to calculate same point in first camera coordinates.

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Xc2   | Yc2   | Xс1   | Yс1   |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1250 |   433 |   209 |   771 |
|   528 |   452 |  1277 |   730 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
# `Xc1` and `Yc1` just estimated for example - need to be calculated
```

Also we have camera 2 calibration data from OpenCV.

Thanks.

P.s. I would greatly appreciate if you'll describe how to do it using python + numpy

P.s.s. And also if you'll describe it like for a rubber duck (*wenk*) :)

Comment: Stack Overflow is **NOT** a code writing service. We are always glad to help and support new coders *but you need to help yourself first. :-)* You are expected to try to write the code yourself. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Just some simple example or formulas still will be good enough)

Comment: Simple example? Yes, thats what a MCVE aims at. Formulas? Not sure about them.

Comment: Why do your world coords come in pairs? What does it mean having for example two X world values but only one X cam value?

Comment: @PaulPanzer it's corresponding coordinates for some plate (quadrilateral)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to consider carefully the geometry of your scene, however linear algebra may give you reasonable results.

If we take a your *world coordinates* to fit the general form `aX + bY +c` then we can make a least-squares fit using [numpy's lstsq](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html#numpy.linalg.lstsq) function.

```html
world = numpy.array([
    [0,0,0],
    [7,0,0],
    [0,5,0],
    [7,4,0]])
    
camera = numpy.array([
    [582,344],
    [834,338],
    [586,529],
    [841,522]])
    
#Lose Z axis
world = world[:,0:2]

#Make a square matrix
A = numpy.vstack([world.T, numpy.ones(4)]).T

#perform the least squares method
x, res, rank, s = numpy.linalg.lstsq(A, camera, rcond=None)

#test results
print(numpy.dot(A,x))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Probably that is what i needed :)